# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lnu/xom/Builder - Xml to json converting not working

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I am new to Android and doing a school project whereby I have to make my own app from scratch. I am doing an `HTTPrequest` towards an API, which gives me a `dataset` in xml back. I want to convert that to `JSON` for some reasons. I've already read a lot about the `json-lib` to convert the xml towards json, but I keep getting an error.

This is a part of my code, which causes the error:

```
 try {
    String xml = result;
    XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    JSON json = xmlSerializer.read( xml );
```

I've implemented the following libraries:

- apache-commons-lang.jar
- json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
- java-json.jar.zip

And I keep getting this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.example.josien.programmeerproject2, PID: 2813
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lnu/xom/Builder;
>
> at net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer.read(XMLSerializer.java:309)
>
> at com.example.jj.programmeerproject2.Train_AsyncTask.onPostExecute(Train_AsyncTask.java:68)
>
> at com.example.jj.programmeerproject2.Train_AsyncTask.onPostExecute(Train_AsyncTask.java:20)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "nu.xom.Builder" on path: DexPathList[[dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.josien.programmeerproject2/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_00b8b06029b068a524b039060787b6e287c3e6d2-classes.dex"

Of course I googled a lot about this error, but unfortunately I can't find the answer. Can anyone help me? Would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "nu.xom.Builder" on
>   path: DexPathList[[dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.josien.programmeerproject2/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_00b8b06029b068a524b039060787b6e287c3e6d2-classes.dex"

This means that the class Builder is not found in your project setup. I think that you are trying to use a jar file, without having the project setup properly to use the jar file. If you want more information, I would need to know exactly how your project is setup (uml diagram, a diagram showing the file structure of the project, as well as the project's settings).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I really want more information on how to solve this problem. How can we do that? My project is on GitHub, including diagrams of the project (although they are not completely up-to-date). I can also tell at what activies/classes you have to look at. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add me to the repo, username in git is also PMARINA